# Preventing HTML encoding in kotlinx.html DSL

Tags: html, kotlin, dsl, kotlinx

I am using kotlinx.html DSL to generate an HTML DIV. One of the DIV's attributes is a URL with `&` in it. e.g. Parameter `url` below is `https://www.example.com?a=1&b=2`

```
fun createDiv(url: String): DIV.() -> Unit {
  return {
    attributes["data-url"] = url
  }
}
```

I was hoping to generate
`<div data-url="https://www.example.com?a=1&b=2">`
But I am actually getting
`<div data-url="https://www.example.com?a=1&amp;b=2">`

How can I prevent the URL from being HTML encoded? Thanks!

P.S. I've tried `unsafe`. But my actual DIV is a bit too complex to be put into an `unsafe` construct as a string. I am using Kotlin 1.4.